# OpenCart 2.3: Mixed content error in admin login blocking login

Tags: https, opencart

I just installed OpenCart 2.3 and tried to login into admin panel, but it is just refreshing the page.  I checked both config.php and both are correctly stating `https`.

Now what can I do to fix this.  In browser console, it is showing 'Mixed Content Error'.  I have read multiple threads related to HTTPS and SSL before posting here but I can't find anything relevant.

Note 1: I checked in 'Network' tab in Developer Tools.  It seems the CSS and JS files are getting blocked. Also while entering incorrect password, I am not getting any error.

Note 2: My `config.php` is:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://example.in/products/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.in/products/');
```

Comment: Can you open up the developer tools in your browser, switch to the "network" tab, and look for `HTTP` requests there?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Are the blocked CSS and JS files on your local install or are they third party?   I don't know much about OpenCart, but in other content management systems the CSS and JS are controlled by the theme.  Are you using a theme with OpenCart?

Comment: They are not 3rd party but part of the package

Comment: Are there themes involved, or is this the base OpenCart package?

Comment: This is the base opencart package.